# Cannot create tags using tortois svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In simply i need to create a tag for my code and i need to create this tag inside `/tags/Source Code/phase1` [image: This is how my svn file structure]

For creating tags inside `/tags/Source Code/phase` folder do i need to create the 2 folder like `Source Code` and  `phase1` in the svn before create the tag or is it create automatically when just provide the path?

Comment: Can you please edit your question? I didn't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: Explain what you're doing, step by step; join a screenshot if needed; and specify the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tortoise SVN will create the directory if only the first one is specified under `tags` (e.g. *Source Code*), but not if more than one deep are specified (e.g. *Source Code/phase2*).

Command-line client has an option for creating intermediate directories (`svn copy --parents`). So you can use that. Alternatively, you can check out `tags` into a fresh working copy with *Immediate children* checkout depth, svn-add *Source Code/phase2* there, svn-copy whatever you need from another working copy, and then commit thus avoiding intermediate revisions (which will happen if you add directories in separate steps) that do not really make sense.

Comment: Oh thanks malenkiy i have created the folder Source key folder in the svn and provide /tags/Source Code/phase1 folder when i tag the code. Thanks your post worked for me.